# Using MultipeerConnectivity.framework to send and receive photos and text files

Tags: ios, bluetooth, airdrop

I want to give to the user of my app the ability to share a photograph without having an internet connection. It is quite hard to explain but I'll do my best. Basically in my app a user can press on a plus button to take a shot using their iPhone. This image is then uploaded on the Internet (Dropbox) in a common folder that can be accessed by all app users. When other users open the app, the image that has been uploaded is downloaded on their device. Since there might be more than one image, the app refreshes itself once in a while, and downloads the new photographs. I want to do the same thing using the bluetooth (or airdrop). When one device takes a picture, this is saved on the device, and sent to all app users nearby. These users can edit it, send it back to the original device where it can be accessed by everyone. basically the original device acts as a server, and all other devices stream the information from that device. The whole purpose of this is to have, say 15 different iOS devices all in the same room in sync which display the same exact thing. When someone edits, all the other people will see it, as if they where in sync with "the cloud" (which now is Dropbox).

I understood that this might be possible with `MultipeerConnectivity.framework` as it permits more than one device to be connected at the same time. I also found an example app called beam it: http://arctouch.com/beamit/

What I'm asking here is not really for some code, rather some indications on how I could approach the problem.